# How to use Microsoft graph to get an url to an image in onedrive using php

Tags: php, api, onedrive

Im using Microsoft Graph 1.85 sdk for PHP to manage file management in a onedrive account , after getting an access token i succeeded to upload & download files using this syntax

```
use Microsoft\Graph\Graph;
$graph = new Graph();
$graph->setAccessToken($user_accessToken);
// upload
$graph->createRequest("PUT", "/me/drive/root:/" . $folder_in_onedrive . $file . ":/content")->upload($uploadfile);
// download
 $graph->createRequest("GET", "/me/drive/root:/" . $folder_in_onedrive . $anotherfile . ":/content")->download($target_dir . $anotherfile);
```

And now i want to make another request type get [sharing link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/onedrive/developer/rest-api/api/driveitem_createlink?view=odsp-graph-online) in the graph api
with parameters of type and scope, i know in the documentation the request should be like :

```
$graph->createRequest("POST", "/me/drive/root:/" . $folder_in_onedrive . $file . ":/createLink")
/* Now im pretty sure d'ont know how to handle this type of request to get the url to the file in my case an image to display*/
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After searching in the graph example and documentation , i managed to get a solution and many options you can use to get the file url
Using createLink for options like type and permissions edit and anonymous are by default:

```
$link = $graph->createRequest("POST", "/me/drive/root:/" . $folder_in_onedrive . $filename . ":/createLink")
    ->addHeaders(["Content-Type" => "application/json"])
    ->setReturnType( Microsoft\Graph\Model\SharingLink::class)
    ->execute();

    print_r($link);^
```

Another sample way is to get the url directly from a GET request of a DriveItem Model like this:

```
$link = $graph->createRequest("GET", "/me/drive/root:/" . $folder_in_onedrive . $file)
    ->addHeaders(["Content-Type" => "application/json"])
    ->setReturnType(Microsoft\Graph\Model\DriveItem::class)
    ->execute();
echo $link->getWebUrl();
```

Hope it help someone.